# Reindexing foreign key constraint fails on Attribute's Index

Tags: database, indexing, index

I am getting this error when I try to re-index the Attribute's Index on my magento 1.9.2.4 site.

Here is a excerpt from the image below

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cmc_mag`.`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE O)' in /home/cmcadm1n/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable magento DB logging via: lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php .

protected $_debug = false; 
protected $_logAllQueries = false; 
protected $_logCallStack = false; 
protected $_debugFile = ‘var/debug/sql.txt’;

Change all to true and then run the re-index. Then check the log file specified above.

Remove the column that shouldn't be there.